# Is the TSCP chess engine able to run on a 32 bit processor?

Tags: engines, software, programming

I'm a beginner learning about chess engines and would like to find a chess engine written in C (like TSCP) that doesn't use bitboards for board representation because I want to test the engine on a 32 bit processor. Though I can tell TSCP doesn't use bitboard, I'd really appreciate it if anyone can clarify for me if TSCP requires a 32 or 64 bit processor to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although pretty much everything even a mobile phone runs on the 64 bits, there is no reason why TSCP can't be run on a 32 bits architecture. In fact, it was written before 64 bits became common. TSCP can be run on any architecture as long as you can compile it, there is no platform-dependent code.

Bitboard is simply a 64-bits integer, that doesn't mean you can't use it on a 32-bits machine. Your machine would need at least an extra instruction cycle to transfer a 64-bit integer on a 32 bit machine, but everything still works.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR **Absolutely!!**

In fact, I see no reason why it will not run on a microcontroller. Possibly a side project for someone to do one day.

It should work fine (as it says it requires less than 64KB of RAM) which on a PC is already provided. :D

As for the 64-bit integers, where are you seeing those? Didn't see that in my copy of the code.